# Python - How to filter out data in Excel

Tags: python, excel, filter

Excel has one tab, Sheet1 (61 columns and 20k rows) and need to select all rows that have in 5th column (column name is Country) value 'UK' and in 38th column (column name is Status) value 'Yes'. Then all of those filtered rows copy to new Sheet2.

Comment: Please share the code sample of yours. What and where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can do all of this with Pandas. First you read your excel file, then filter the dataframe and save to the new sheet

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name=0) #reads the first sheet of your excel file

df = df[(df['Country']=='UK') & (df['Status']=='Yes')] #Filtering dataframe

df.to_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name='Filtered Data') #Saving to a new sheet called Filtered Data
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to delete old sheets while operating on this file in the future, use this.
Pandas is a python library which help you (but not limited to) play around with excels and csv's.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
df = pd.read_excel('Path/to/folder/filename.xlsx')
filtered_df = df[df['Country']=='UK' & df['Status']=='Yes']
book = load_workbook('Path/to/folder/filename.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Path/to/folder/filename.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book
filtered_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'sheet2')
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: HI, I am getting this error:

File "<ipython-input-2-cfd97e4fa2a2>", line 2, in <module>
    filtered_df = df[df['Country']=='UK' & df['Status']=='Yes']

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1360, in wrapper
    res_values = na_op(self.values, other)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1326, in na_op
    typ=type(y).__name__))

TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Comment: No worries, I have sorted the error with brackets "filtered_df = df[(df['Country']=='UK') & (df['Status']=='Yes')]". Thank you. 

Also one more (last) question, if I want to Apply OR within the filter so for example Status == Yes OR Maybe, how do I do it? Thanks guys.

Comment: Use the Or symbol which is as below
|